# Visual Studio Code - JS refactoring

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm familiar with VCS refactor quick actions. I find extracting code to function very useful.
But, is there a way to "extract to arrow function"?

Comment: Upvote this feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31860

Answer (score 1):

You need an add-on for that.

The free
[JS Refactor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cmstead.jsrefactor)
seems to have the functionality of (quote)
"Convert To Arrow Function".